# PIL and skimage taking too long to load 56000 URL's

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

My dataframe `data3` has 56000 rows, with an image thumbnail URL as one of its column values. I am evaluating whether each one of those images are low contrast or not. I let the code below run for 9 hours! but still no result, and the kernel was still busy. Can you please let me know whats wrong?

P.S. I tried the code with a subset of my dataframe (100 rows) and it took 3 seconds to succesfully run. Surely by that standard, 56000 rows should take 30 minutes. Is there a memory overrun happening with temp files or something?
Maybe I need to introduce a try block here to catch any exceptions (even though no error is showing)? I'm not sure how to do that.

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request
import skimage

def f(row):

    URL=row['ThumbnailURL']

    #URL = 'http://www.moma.org/media/W1siZiIsIjU5NDA1Il0sWyJwIiwiY29udmVydCIsIi1yZXNpemUgMzAweDMwMFx1MDAzZSJdXQ.jpg?sha=137b8455b1ec6167'

    with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as url:
        with open('temp.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(url.read())

    tutu = Image.open('temp.jpg')

    val=skimage.exposure.is_low_contrast(tutu, fraction_threshold=0.4, lower_percentile=1, upper_percentile=99, method='linear')

    return val

data3['lowcontornot'] = data3.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: 56000 rows is quite a lot to analyze, there's not much you can do apart from get a better cpu or run it on a powerful vps

Comment: but if 100 rows takes 3 seconds, 56000 rows should take 30 minutes!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below avoids saving temporary images to disk, thus reducing the overhead:

```
def f(row):
    url = row['ThumbnailURL']
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(url).content))
    return is_low_contrast(img, fraction_threshold=0.4, lower_percentile=1, 
                           upper_percentile=99, method='linear')
```

To give this code a try you need to include the following imports:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from skimage.exposure import is_low_contrast
```